# Создание области бина в пределах страницы

Tags: java, spring, scope

Цель создать класс ScopePage, который обеспечивает область видимости бинов в пределах страницы. Корректно ли он создан, если нет то как его можно переписать?

```
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

public class PageScope extends AbstractRequestAttributesScope {

    private final int scope;
    private final String WIN_ID = "WINID";

    public PageScope() {
        this.scope = 10;
    }

    public PageScope(boolean globalSession) {
        this.scope = (globalSession ? RequestAttributes.SCOPE_GLOBAL_SESSION
                : 10);
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(String name, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") ObjectFactory objectFactory) {
        Object mutex = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()
                .getSessionMutex();
        synchronized (mutex) {
            ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                    .currentRequestAttributes();
            String winId = getWinId(attributes.getRequest());
            winId = winId.replaceAll("NEWWINDOW", "");
            String identifier = winId + ":" + name;
            Object scopedObject = attributes.getAttribute(identifier,
                    getScope());
            if (scopedObject == null) {
                scopedObject = objectFactory.getObject();
                attributes.setAttribute(identifier, scopedObject, getScope());
            }
            return scopedObject;
        }
    }

    private String getWinId(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        String wi = null; // window ID
        for (Cookie c : cookies) {
            if (c.getName().equals(WIN_ID)) {
                wi = c.getValue();
            }
        }
        wi = wi == null ? "" : wi;
        return wi;
    }

    @Override
    public String getConversationId() {
        return RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getScope() {
        return scope;
    }

}
```